# Разметка TextView Java Android

Tags: java

приветы. ситуация такая: имеется листвью, в нем нное количество итемов. в этих итемах один TextView. так вот, мне нужно маленькую картинку размером 20 на 20 dp вставить поверх последнего символа в этом текствью. возможно ли это? вот примерно как я сделал, но этот вариант не пойдет, ибо текст может быть широким, либо узким.

```
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/Text"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Good"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    />

<ImageView
       android:id="@+id/image"
       android:layout_width="20dp"
       android:layout_height="20dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:src="@drawable/image"
       />
```

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, единственный вариант - сабклассить `TextView` и переопределять у него `onDraw`, отрисовывая в нём последовательно сам текст и требуемое изображение. Узнать ширину строки и позицию определённого символа на экране можно через `TextPaint` (вызов `getPaint` у `TextView`).